# Find the angle between the unit vectors

Tags: vectors

Find the angle between the unit vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ if the vectors $\vec{a}+2\vec{b}$ and $\vec5{a}-4\vec{b}$ are perpendicular.

I am stuck on the fact that the given vectors are perpendicular. How can we use that? Their dot product is $0$, but this doesn't help much.

Comment: Yes, use the fact that their dot product is $0$, expand $(\vec a + 2 \vec b) \cdot (5 \vec a - 4 \vec b)$, and leverage the fact that $\vec a \cdot \vec b = \vec b \cdot \vec a$ to gather like terms.

Comment: $(a+2b).(5a-4b)=5|a|^2-8|b|^2+6(a.b)=0\Longrightarrow a.b=... \Longrightarrow \theta=...$

Comment: @prets, thank you! I arrived at $\cos\varphi=\dfrac12$. So $\varphi$ can be equal to $60^\circ$. Can it accept other values?

Comment: I think no. The only value is $60^0$

Comment: @koki There are of course other angles $\varphi$ for which $\cos(\varphi) = 1/2$---you should convince yourself that those in fact give you the "same" answer in some reasonable sense.